# How to send log data to a remote server in a Python-Flask serverless function running in Vercel without making the main function wait

Tags: python, flask, serverless, serverless-framework, vercel

The following is a minimum working example of my Python/Flask, which is working as the back-end of my web app. It is hosted in Vercell and it is working as a "serverless function". I'm keeping a log of the incoming requests and I have to write this to a remote server. Now, I'm using the `Process` submodule from `multiprocessing` to send the log data. I use this approach because, sometimes the writing log data can take several seconds and the main function will have to wait till then.

However, the problem is that since this is working as a serverless function, the request is closed as soon as the `return` statement is executed, and about half of the time the log data is not being written.

What is the best way to write log data to a remote server in such a situation? Without having to make the main function wait and also making sure that the log data is being written?

```py
from flask import Flask, request,  jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def  remote_log (log_data):
    time.sleep(1)
    return 0

def send_data_to_server(log_data):
    remote_log(log_data=log_data)

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Server Deployed'

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'About'

@app.route('/api/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat():

    log_data = "This is my data"

    # this is where the problem is 
    p = Process(target=send_data_to_server, args= (log_data,))
    p.start()

    return "My response"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Could not reproduce. multiprocessing keeps its own internal reference to the process so that it can handle cleanup. Normally a parent process will wait for its subprocesses to exit. But you can set the daemon flat to have the parent kill child processes on exit. But here the flask server keeps running so it doesn't matter either wiay.

Comment: I think you'd be better off creating the logging child process once, give it a multiprocessing.Queue and use logging.handlers.QueueHandler to pass logging to the child. That's a single process handling all of the logging. You could likelly do the same thing with threading instead as the logging time is likely spent waiting for I/O.